# lambda expressions with filter function; issues with var type

Tags: python, lambda, filter

(scroll down to the last two paragraphs for the tl;dr version)

I'm having an issue with the filter command and lambda functions:

```
sample_list = ["Fri", 4, "Sat", 6, "Sun", 4, 8.50]
for item in sample_list:
    day = filter(lambda item: item is str and sample_list.index(x) >= sample_list.index(item), sample_list)
    print item
    print type(item)
    hours = filter(lambda x: x is int and sample_list.index(x) >= sample_list.index(item) + 1, sample_list)
    print day, hours
```

(sorry if it's a little long)

the output reads that the item type is str, for example, even though the "item is str" condition in the lambda expression evaluates to false, making the return [].
Here is the sample output:

```
Fri
(type 'str')
[] []
4
(type 'int')
[] []
Sat
(type 'str')
[] []
6
(type 'int')
```

while I want the output to read something like     
`Fri 4
Sat 6`

I'm just confused as to why the lambda expression seems to evaluate to False for "item is str" or "item is int."

For the record, I know that the print statements ought to have parentheses, I'm just using a web browser learning tool for Python that I assume runs an older version. When I was using 3.4.3 version, The output would return something like  (I don't have the actual output, it was something like that). I already looked up a solution to that specific issue, but I couldn't make heads or tails of it.

What it boils down to is I think there's an issue with the lambda expression confusing variable types. If you could offer advice, I'd really appreciate it. Also, I'm somewhat new to Python, so if you could use layman's terms that would help me understand better.

Comment: Note that `'a' is str` evaluautes to `False`, and `1 is int` evaluates to `False`. Use `type('a') == str` instead....

Answer (score 0):

Your type check should read `isinstance(item, str)` and `isinstance(item, int)`. Also, your first filter appears to confuse what's `x` and what's `item`; I'd expect a `NameError` wrt. `x` to be raised.